# Using JOIN, or Sub-query (SELECT within SELECT) to roll 3 rows in to 1

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, gaps-and-islands

I have an Oracle SQL view with an ID, TIME_STAMP, LOCATION and a "COMMAND" variable which is used to describe "Time IN", "Time Requested" and "Time Out" as an integer 1, 2, 3, respectively, such as:

| ID | Time | Command | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:20:00 | 1 | 51 |
| 2 | 00:22:00 | 1 | 52 |
| 1 | 00:30:00 | 2 | 51 |
| 1 | 00:32:00 | 3 | 51 |
| 2 | 00:40:00 | 2 | 52 |
| 2 | 00:43:00 | 3 | 52 |
| 1 | 00:50:00 | 1 | 52 |
| 1 | 00:52:00 | 2 | 52 |
| 3 | 01:10:00 | 1 | 53 |
| 1 | 01:22:00 | 3 | 52 |
| 3 | 01:40:00 | 2 | 53 |
| 3 | 01:52:00 | 3 | 53 |

I would like to group the IDs of Time IN, REQ, and OUT into one row, for each ID visit to each location, to get the result:

| ID | Time IN | Time REQ | Time OUT | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:20:00 | 00:30:00 | 00:32:00 | 51 |
| 2 | 00:22:00 | 00:40:00 | 00:43:00 | 52 |
| 1 | 00:50:00 | 00:52:00 | 01:22:00 | 53 |
| 3 | 01:10:00 | 01:40:00 | 01:52:00 | 52 |

---

I achieved this by searching where command = 1 (all IN instances) and then using a SELECT in the SELECT statement

```
SELECT 
O.ID AS "ID", 
O.TIME AS "TIMEIN", 

(SELECT 
    MIN(TIME)
    FROM VIEW I
    WHERE O.LOCATION = I.LOCATION AND COMMAND = ('2') AND O.ID = I.ID AND O.TIME < I.TIME) 
AS "TIMEREQ",

(SELECT 
    MIN(TIME)
    FROM VIEW I
    WHERE O.LOCATION = I.LOCATION AND COMMAND = ('3') AND O.ID = I.ID AND O.TIME < I.TIME) 
AS "TIMEOUT",

O.LOCATION AS "LOCATION" 

FROM VIEW O
WHERE 
LOCATION IN ('52','53','54') AND COMMAND IN ('1')
ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

The results of this takes ~11s for 12,000 rows.

When I then tried to JOIN a table to this, which just contains:

| ID | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello, World! |
| 2 | Test comment |

The view never loads, tried up to ~50s, but either way this is too slow and I'm expecting incorrect.

I've tried to use a different approach by using a SELECT statement within the JOIN statement to see if the performance was any better but I'm struggling to get it to work:

```
SELECT 
P.ID AS "ID",
P.TIME AS "TIMEIN",
TIMECOM2 AS "TIMEREQ",
P.LOCATION AS "LOCATION",
P.COMMAND AS "COMMAND"

FROM VIEW P
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
MAX(C.ID) AS "REQID",
MIN(C.TIME) AS "TIMECOM2"
FROM VIEW C
WHERE C.COMMAND = 2 AND C.LOCATION IN (52, 53, 54) AND C.ID = '2253') 
ON (P.ID = REQID) AND TIMECOM2 > P.TIME

WHERE 
P.ID = '2253' AND
P.LOCATION IN (52, 53, 54) AND 
P.COMMAND = 1
ORDER BY P.TIME, TIMECOM2
```

I tried many different approaches in the above, but that was the last attempt, and note I only tried with TIMEREQ and picked a specific ID to try to get it to work in the first instance. I think my issue lies in not being able to use VIEW P in the SELECT statement, such as P.TIME > C.TIME in the WHERE statement. I am getting such results:

| ID | TIMEIN | TIMEREQ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2253 | 31-OCT-22 22:20:15 | 31-OCT-22 22:40:11 |
| 2253 | 01-NOV-22 09:40:19 | (null) |
| 2253 | 01-NOV-22 11:04:59 | (null) |
| 2253 | 01-NOV-22 18:21:19 | (null) |
| 2253 | 01-NOV-22 19:20:38 | (null) |

Which I don't understand - I can get it to show the MIN or MAX date in each row, or the MIN or MAX in the first row, or all others..

Also, could anyone explain why SELECT statements within SELECT statements are slow, or am I missing something? Obviously I don't know if JOIN is any faster as I failed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple correlated subqueries, we can try and address this as a gaps-and-islands problem.

An island starts with a command `1` at a given location and id : we can compute this
with a cumulative sum ; the rest is conditional aggregation:

```
select id, location,
    min(time) time_in,
    max(case when command = 2 then time end) time_req,
    max(case when command = 3 then time end) time_out
from (
    select v.*,
        sum(case when command = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id, location order by time) grp
    from myview v
) t
group by id, location, grp
```

Note that this properly manages incomplete islands (ie that do not have all 3 commands) ; in that event, dates of missing commands will appear as `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked and is getting responses so much quicker, although some of the results aren't working.. some are showing the same IN and OUT time and no REQ time. I'll look into why this could be and respond.

Comment: @FuzzUK: *the same IN and OUT time and no REQ time* : seems like you have duplicates in your data.`select id, location, time, count(*) from myview group by id, location, time having count(*) > 1`

Comment: Yes you are right - I have a few issues in the original table. Command 2 is sometimes missing, but there is another Command '5' which could be used as a CASE? If so could you advise where it could go? FYI, there may be 2 between Com 1 and 3, so a MIN/MAX? Also sometimes there is an anomaly where a 'fake' entry gets put in, can you explain how I can exclude these if 'USER_COMMAND' = 80. I solved this by inserting 'WHERE USER_COMMAND <> 80' prior to the 'GROUP BY ID, LOCATION, GRP' in your answer. Do you have any explanation/further reading on how your answer works so I can understand it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    t
pivot  (min(time) for command in(1 as time_in,2 as time_req,3 as time_out)) p left join t2 using(ID)
```

| ID | LOCATION | TIME_IN | TIME_REQ | TIME_OUT | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 51 | 00:20:00 | 00:30:00 | 00:32:00 | Hello, World! |
| 1 | 52 | 00:50:00 | 00:52:00 | 01:22:00 | Hello, World! |
| 2 | 52 | 00:22:00 | 00:40:00 | 00:43:00 | Test comment |
| 3 | 53 | 01:10:00 | 01:40:00 | 01:52:00 | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MybhZBog)